# Ubuntu freezes on every single desktop environment

Tags: drivers, 16.04, gnome, kernel, kde

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04LTS on my desktop, however every single desktop environment that I try will freeze after login(mouse still able to move). I have tried Gnome, KDE, Xfce, Lxde, Unity even i3...

To solve this, I have installed Nvidia's proprietary and ubuntu-provided 750ti drivers. However, even with the drivers installed successfully the problem still exists.

Then after some research, I found out that updating the kernel might fix the freeze so I did upgraded to 4.7 or 4.8, the freeze still exists...

Also I have tried OpenSUSE, Debian, Mageia and Arch... All of them have the same problem. Which lead me to think that there is problem with the Xserver since all of those distros share this program.

lspci output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B) (rev 02)
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B)
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port D)
00:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port H)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller (rev 40)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VL805 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
05:07.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
```

Desktop spec:

- AMD FX8350 CPU
- 8GB of RAM
- Nvidia 750ti GPU
- 1 TB WD
- Gigabyte
  GA-970A-DS3P ATX AM3+ Motherboard

If you have any idea of what could be the causing factor please help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked your BIOS firmware?

For Rev 2 boards:
http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5216#bios

For Rev 1 boards:
http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4591#bios

Let me know if that helps. Cheers, Al

*edit: I had the rev/url's reversed.*

Comment: I checked I have rev 1.0 and its all upped to date.

Comment: Does the freezing still occur if you boot directly to a Ubuntu Live DVD?  Does it work in a Windows OS? Cheers, Al

Comment: Yes if I boot directly into the live DVD still have the freezing. However this never happened on Windows 10.

Comment: How long does it take to freeze? How much RAM do you have? Try this... power off the computer and **disconnect** your hard drive's data and power cables. Disconnect your ethernet cable. Boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD again and see if it still freezes. Cheers, Al

Comment: It turns out to be the problem of my GPU's BIOS. All I needed to do was to update the BIOS, although the BIOS update application is only available in Windows so I had to install it on Windows then to run Linux again. Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Good news! Cheers, Al